# Trying all possibilities in java

Tags: java

I have 4 ints (a,b,c,d) and 3 Strings that represent mathematical operators (+,-,*,/).
I want to check if it's possible to make a certain number (e) from these ints and Strings.

for example:

a + b * c - d == e;

The ints can be used only once each, and the operators can be used multiple times, but only once between every 2 ints.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is this homework? then you should tag it as that

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)#Numbers_round ?

Comment: I made a math game once, where the user had to think of a formula for `e`, and the computer would give a solution. Here I wonder: (1) can it also be `d - a * c == e`, (2) is normal operator precedence used, or would the evaluation be `(d - a) * c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First break down your problem into smaller pieces.

I would break it down as follows:

1. calculate all permutations of the 4 ints. There should be 4!(24) of these. (look up generating permutations)
2. calculate all combinations of the 3 operations that can occur. there
   should be 3*3 (9) of these. (look up generating permutations with
   repeats).
3. now that you have the order of the intergers and the order of the operations try and compute e. (interweave the combinations: ie. 1 from ints, 1 from ops, 2nd from ints, second from ops ect...) This should be done with all int permuations and all op combinations.
4. after evaluating all equations (216 of these) if none of them were equal to e, there is no solution.